# Backbone view not removing properly?

Tags: backbone.js

There is something I'm missing here it seems my view is not removing.

```
// ROUTER //

screensaveroff: function() {
   AnimationManager.outAnimation([self.screensaverView], function() {
        console.log($(this.screensaverView.el).length); //!! always trigger 1 !!
   });  


}

// ANIMATION MANAGER outANimation function (trigger outAnimation for the passed view as arg)// 
 outAnimation : function(animationArray, callback){
            var time = [];
            window.animationArray   = animationArray;
            for (var i=0; i<animationArray.length; i++)
            {
                var view =  animationArray[i];
                    view.outAnimation();
                time[i] = animationArray[i].animationTime;
            }
            var timeoutMax = Math.max.apply(null, time);
            setTimeout(function(){callback()},timeoutMax);
        }

// screensaverView outANimation function //

outAnimation: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.$el.slideToX(1920, self.animationTime, function() {
                self.clearIntervalAnimation();
                self.remove();
            });
        },
```

any idea what's wrong with my code ?? thanks a lot

Comment: Does self really refer to the correct this? Try adding a debugger just before self.remove() and see in develper tools if self really is correct..

Comment: What is `clearIntervalAnimation`? What is `self` in `screensaveroff`? Does anything clean up `window.animationArray`? What is `AnimationManager`? BTW, `$(some_dom_node).length` should always be `1`.